# Can't make basic example of Serde Serialize work

Tags: rust, serde

Serde documentation says:

> All of these can be serialized using Serde out of the box.
>
> serde_json is just for the example, not required in general.

This is exactly what I need, a basic serialization of a struct into some basic binary format. I don't need JSON format, I want to keep it simple to be able to store struct in a file or send it to the network. The documentation is not clear on how to use serde for basic (binary or default) serialization, it only shows example with a  JSON but this is not what I am looking for. I also don't want to implement my own `serialize` method, I want to use the default methods that Serde provides.

This is my example, so how do I make it work?

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize,Serializer};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };

    //let serialized = serde::serialize(&point).unwrap(); // <-- doesnt work!
    //let serialized = Serializer::serialize(&point); // <-- doesnt work!
    //let serialized = point.serialize(Serializer); // <-- doesn't work!
    println!("data = {:?}", serialized);
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b57a77399280f19664bb004201319b32

This is my dependency line:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

Comment: What are you trying to serialise **to**? Yes, you don't need to depend on `serde_json`, but you need to serialise to something. Otherwise, what does "serialise" mean to you?

Comment: "The documentation is not clear on how to use serde for basic (binary or default) serialization" That would be because there isn't such a thing as a standard binary serialization format everyone agrees with. There are literally dozens of those. You have to pick one, that's not serde's job.

Comment: @PeterHall good question, whatever compact binary is available to use it for storage (or transfer) will be enough. But my point is that Serde docs says that there is everything `out of the box` , so what is packaged and what can I use from this "box" to quickly serialize into some `blob`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there's no "default" format provided.

You have to pick the binary format you want and include it as an additional dependency, just as you would with `serde_json`.

There's a list of formats at https://serde.rs/#data-formats. Of those `serde_json` is the only package hosted under https://github.com/serde-rs, all the binary formats are "third-party". Cross-referencing it with [the list of crates tagged "serde" sorted by recent downloads](https://crates.io/keywords/serde), the [CBOR](https://github.com/pyfisch/cbor) crate seems popular.